Match with a loop in VBA Excel
Would you be kind enough to assist me with this matter, please i want to bring some data from another sheet in the same workbook if the IDs matched.
So basically there will be a designated area on a separate sheet where i will be pasting the new data daily and in the main sheet ( contains around 1200 row) only if the IDs are a match it needs to bring equivalent name and date date and maybe other details.
I know that might be too much but it’s not necessary writing me the code, if you could it would be much appreciated otherwise just direct me how i can proceed with this and which formulas, loops and techniques i can use.
Thank you so much guys.
I have tried something with some loops and but it’s not accurate and a i got a pot of errors

Look around here with searching lookup values on other sheet [vba] or without [vba] for formula results. A lot of solutions can be found. Try to use/adapt  them and if you are stucked then modify your question with the issue.

It would be good to follow the above advice. But if you expect an answer from somebody wishing to help, it would be necessary to be more specific. Are the mentioned IDs unique in both matching sheets? Will the necessary data to be returned be extracted from the the same column(s) always? According to your specific needs more approaches my be possible and it is good that the most suitable to be chosen, I think. You can use range 'Findin a loop, if more occurrences of the same ID in he searching sheet (to cumulate data),Matchfor unique ID etc. Even returnApplication.Vlookup` in array

It sounds like you might be able to achieve what you need with simple VLOOKUP or INDEX-MATCH.
